# Building a application with TKInter, need some assistance

Tags: python, tkinter

Basically, I've made a GUI application for personal use related to an online gaming community, and I'm kind've stuck currently. It is working as intended, apart from one thing. I need it to be able to track multiple "Activations" and start separate timers but keep track of the previous timers as well, so it can total it up at the end. For example, if I Activate "Service 1" it currently starts a timer, but when I deactivate it and activate it once again, it will disregard the initial timer and just start a new one. How can I make it so it adds the two timers together to print out a "total time spent".

Here is the code relevant to my query

```
def time_convert3(sec):
    global PALenght
    mins = sec // 60
    sec = round(sec % 60)
    hours = mins // 60
    mins = mins % 60
    SIDLenght = ("{0}H:{1}M:{2}S".format(int(hours),int(mins),sec))
    print(PALenght)

def selectPA():
    global PAStart
    global PALenght
    global PACount
    if var.get() == 1:
        PAStart = time.time()
        print(PAStart)
        PACount = PACount + 1
        root.after(10, lambda: Label(root, text= 'PA Activations: ' + str(PACount), bg='#1aa3ff', fg='Black' ).place(relx=0.1, rely=0.85, relwidth=0.3, relheight=0.05))
        root.after(1000, lambda: portA.place(relx=0.4, rely=0.55, relwidth=0.2, relheight=0.05))
        root.after(3000, lambda: portA.place_forget())
    elif var.get() == 0:
        PAEnd = time.time()
        PATotal = PAEnd - PAStart
        time_convert3(PATotal)
        root.after(1000, lambda: portB.place(relx=0.4, rely=0.55, relwidth=0.2, relheight=0.05))
        root.after(3000, lambda: portB.place_forget())

var = IntVar()
PACheck = Checkbutton(root, text="Activate/Deactivate PA ", variable = var,bg='#1aa3ff', fg='Black', command = selectPA).place(relx=0.13, rely=0.55, relwidth=0.2, relheight=0.05)
```

Comment: First you have to get rid of using `global ...` and use a `class object` for every *Service* you want to count.

Comment: I see, could you give me an example of how? I only started working with python and Tkinter 2-3 days ago and I'm brand new.

Comment: when you deactivate timer then you should keep result in list or dictionary so you could later use it to sum total value. Or at least set `PATotal = 0` at start and later add it to `PATotal` (`+= `) instead of assigning (`=`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At start you should set

```
PATotal = 0
```

and later add new time to total

```
PATotal += (PAEnd - PAStart)
```

---

Minimal working example

```
import tkinter as tk
import time

# --- functions ---

def func():
    global total
    global time_start

    if cb_var.get():
        time_start = time.time()
    else:
        total += (time.time() - time_start)
        label['text'] = 'Total: {:.2f}s'.format(total)

# --- main ---

total = 0
time_start = 0

root = tk.Tk()

cb_var = tk.BooleanVar()

label = tk.Label(root, text='Total: 0.00s')
label.pack()

cb = tk.Checkbutton(root, text='Running ...', variable=cb_var, command=func)
cb.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

---

Or at start you create list

```
all_times = []
```

and later append `PAEnd - PAStart` to this  list

```
all_times.append(PAEnd - PAStart)
```

and you can sum all values on list.

```
PATotal = sum(all_times)
```

---

Minimal working example

```
import tkinter as tk
import time

# --- functions ---

def func():
    global total
    global time_start

    if cb_var.get():
        time_start = time.time()
    else:
        all_times.append(time.time() - time_start)
        label_times['text'] += '\n{:.2f}'.format(all_times[-1])

        total = sum(all_times)
        label_total['text'] = 'Total: {:.2f}s'.format(total)

# --- main ---

all_times = []
total = 0
time_start = 0

root = tk.Tk()

cb_var = tk.BooleanVar()

label_times = tk.Label(root, text='Times')
label_times.pack()

label_total = tk.Label(root, text='Total: 0.00s')
label_total.pack()

cb = tk.Checkbutton(root, text='Running ...', variable=cb_var, command=func)
cb.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

[image]